# Core Data delete NSManagedObject in Context take time?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This is my first question on StackOverflow. Pardon me if I make some mistakes.
I'm trying to delete all NSManagedObject ESAnswer in a Submission object.

```c
NSLog(@"BEFORE");
for (ESAnswer *ans in _currentSubmission.answer) {
    NSLog(@"%@", ans.questionID);
}

// Delete all answer with index from _nextQuestionsIndexStack.m_array
for (NSNumber *index in _nextQuestionsIndexStack.m_array) {
    // Find ESAnswer object with questionID
    NSString *questionID = _question[index]; 
    NSPredicate *predicateAnswer = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"questionID LIKE %@", questionID];
ESAnswer *foundAnswer = [[_currentSubmission.answer filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicateAnswer] anyObject];

    // Delete object
    [context deleteObject:foundAnswer];
    NSLog(@"Deleted %@", foundAnswer.questionID);
}

NSLog(@"AFTER");
for (ESAnswer *ans in _currentSubmission.answer) {
    NSLog(@"%@", ans.questionID);
}
```

But the console output was like nothing was deleted (all objects are in the same NSManagedObjectContext):

```
2013-09-18 11:01:36.541[3661:707] BEFORE
2013-09-18 11:01:36.543[3661:707] 52368675231dbba60e000065
2013-09-18 11:01:36.544[3661:707] 522ff38a93ebc0ce4f000008
2013-09-18 11:01:36.545[3661:707] 52368662231dbba60e000060
2013-09-18 11:01:36.553[3661:707] Deleted 52368675231dbba60e000065
2013-09-18 11:01:36.558[3661:707] Deleted 52368662231dbba60e000060
2013-09-18 11:01:36.563[3661:707] Deleted 522ff38a93ebc0ce4f000008
2013-09-18 11:01:36.564[3661:707] AFTER
2013-09-18 11:01:36.565[3661:707] 52368675231dbba60e000065
2013-09-18 11:01:36.567[3661:707] 522ff38a93ebc0ce4f000008
2013-09-18 11:01:36.570[3661:707] 52368662231dbba60e000060
```

These answers should be deleted before I calculate the next step. 
However in runtime, the calculate method is called with the old data before deleting. When I let it stay for a while, the calculate method is called with the new data.

So, my question is:
1. Is that deleting NSManagedObject in a context take some time to complete?
2. If that so, how can I make the calculate method wait for deleting to complete?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deleteObject:` only marks the object for deletion. You can `save` the context, or call
`processPendingChanges` to make the context actually perform the changes to the object graph.

`processPendingChanges` is called automatically during the main event loop, which explains
why you are seeing the changes "later".